# I don't understand how the template function gets to be a friend of the class A::X::Y in the example in [namespace.memdef]/3 in C++14

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++14, friend

Consider the following code from the example in [namespace.memdef]/3 in C++14:

```
// Assume f and g have not yet been declared.
void h(int);
template <class T> void f2(T);
namespace A {
    class X {
        friend void f(X);           // A::f(X) is a friend
        class Y {
            friend void g();        // A::g is a friend
            friend void h(int);     // A::h is a friend
                                    // ::h not considered
            friend void f2<>(int);  // ::f2<>(int) is a friend
        };
    };
    // A::f, A::g and A::h are not visible here
    X x;
    void g() { f(x); }              // definition of A::g
    void f(X) { /* ... */}          // definition of A::f
    void h(int) { /* ... */ }       // definition of A::h
    // A::f, A::g and A::h are visible here and known to be friends
}

using A::x;
void h() {
    A::f(x);
    //A::X::f(x);                  // error: f is not a member of A::X
    //A::X::Y::g();                // error: g is not a member of A::X::Y
}
```

I don't understand why `::f2<>(int)` is a friend of the class `A::X::Y`. Shouldn't the lookup of the name stop at `namespace A`? How is it allowed to find `::f2`? Why is there a difference in the treatment of `h` and `f2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't have to be in namespace `A`. I think the confusion might come from this sentence from [namespace.memdef]/3:

> If the name in a `friend` declaration is neither
>   qualified nor a *template-id* and the declaration is a function or an *elaborated-type-specifier*, the lookup to determine whether the entity has been previously declared shall not consider any scopes outside the innermost
>   enclosing namespace.

The name in the `friend` declaration in question is `f2<>`. That is not qualified, but it *is* a *template-id*. So the clause that would have restricted lookup to namespace `A` simply doesn't apply. We do the standard unqualified lookup on `f2` to find `::f2`.

Consider the difference in the example you copied between `h` and `f2`:

```
friend void h(int);     // A::h is a friend
                        // ::h not considered
friend void f2<>(int);  // ::f2<>(int) is a friend
```

There `h` is neither qualified nor a *template-id*, so we do not look outside of the innermost enclosing namespace. Since we don't find anything for `h` there, we apply the first sentence of [namespace.memdef]/3:

> If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares a class, function, class template or function template
>   the friend is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace.

So that particular line declares a `void A::h(int)`, which is a `friend` of `A::X::Y`.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why a template-id doesn't follow the general rule in this paragraph?

Comment: @LeonTrotski I don't know. So I [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005610/friend-lookup-exception-from-template-id).