# Friend lookup exception from template-id?

Tags: c++, c++11, friend

Consider the following clause in [namespace.memdef]/3:

> If the name in a `friend` declaration is neither
>   qualified nor a *template-id* and the declaration is a function or an *elaborated-type-specifier*, the lookup to determine whether the entity has been previously declared shall not consider any scopes outside the innermost
>   enclosing namespace.

Is there a reason for the exception for *template-id* along with the qualified name? For that matter, is there a reason for the lookup of an unqualified name that isn't a *template-id* to be restricted to the innermost enclosing namespace? Is there a specific problem or use-case that this clause solves?

Comment: Qualified-ids and template-ids cannot declare new members of that namespace (you've left out the note).

Comment: Have you read http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1995/N0783.pdf ?

Comment: @dyp No I haven't, and how do you even find this stuff?  I guess between the note and 1.1 there, that's the answer.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure.. does a friend declaration according to *current rules* introduce the name of a friend into class scope? Also, I get weird results from tests, both clang++ and g++ show strange behaviours (bug?): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/def92f896cfa420e

Comment: @dyp No, first sentence from [namespace.memdef]/3 is: "If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares a class, function, class template or function template the friend is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace." That second declaration should introduce `A::f(int)`, which should be the `f` called from both calls in `B::bf()`.

Comment: @dyp Ah, but "The friend declaration does not by
itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup (3.4.1) or qualified lookup (3.4.3). [ Note: The name of
the friend will be visible in its namespace if a matching declaration is provided at namespace scope (either
before or after the class definition granting friendship). —end note ]". Just need an extra `void f(int );`

Comment: Ah thanks. Meanwhile, I think I've found out that Koenig lookup has been introduced *after* N0783. So this might be an artefact? -- I found N0783 by searching for "friend innermost enclosing namespace" then found N0812 which cites N0783.

Answer (score 5):

## Why doesn't the restriction apply to qualified names and template-ids?

Qualified names and template-ids cannot introduce new members into the enclosing namespace, this is what the note in [namespace.memdef]p3 tries to say:

> [ *Note:* The other forms of `friend` declarations cannot declare a new
>   member of the innermost enclosing namespace and thus follow the usual
>   lookup rules. — *end note* ]

Therefore, no such restriction is necessary for qualified names and template-ids.

Note that template-ids lack the declaration of the template-parameters, and qualified-ids could introduce names into distant, unrelated namespaces.

---

## Why is there a restriction at all?

**This part of the answer is still incomplete, but represents the current state of "research". Feel free to contribute.**

The restriction has (probably?) been introduced due to [N0783 - Namespace Issues and Proposed Resolutions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1995/N0783.pdf) which "attempts to clarify a number of namespace issues that are currently either undefined or incompletely specified".

This paper from 1995 contains two enlightening discussions of issues related to declarations of entities introduced via friend-declarations. Bear in mind that the name lookup rules back then were different:

- Argument-dependent lookup had not yet been introduced<sup>(*)</sup>
- Names introduced via friend-declarations are not found via pure unqualified lookup (no ADL) according to current rules, see [namespace.memdef]p3 and [CWG 1477](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1477). The examples from N0878 suggest that those names could be found via pure unqualified lookup at that time.

<sup>(*)</sup> The best I could find was [N0878](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1996/N0878.pdf) from March 1996, which says *"A change was recently made to the working paper to add the “Koenig lookup rule”"*

First, the example from N0783 for functions:

> ```
> void f(char);
>
> namespace A {
>     class B {
>         friend void f(char);   // ::f(char) is a friend
>         friend void f(int);    // A::f(int) is a friend
>
>         void bf();
>     };
>     void B::bf()
>     {
>         f(1);  // calls A::f(int);
>         f('x');  // also calls A::f(int) because ::f is hidden
>     }
> }
> ```

The second friend declaration must introduce a new function. N0783 tries to specify in which scope this declaration is introduced. It suggests

> All friend declarations for a given name must declare entities in one
>   particular scope.

as a general rule, to avoid the surprises of situations such as the above.

> So the question is, which scope do they declare entities in? There are
>   two possibilities, either
>
> 1. When looking for a previous declaration of the function, look until the nearest enclosing namespace is reached, or
> 2. When looking for a previous declaration, look in all enclosing scopes for the *name* of the function that was declared. If a previous
>      use of the name is found, the declaration is injected into that scope.
>      If no previous use of the name is found the friend is injected into
>      the nearest enclosing namespace scope.
>
> Rule #2 would mean that the presence of any function called `f` in an
>   enclosing scope, whether or not the types match, would be enough to
>   cause a friend declaration to inject into that scope.
>
> I believe that rule #2 is clearly unacceptable. A friend declaration
>   in a namespace would be affected by *any* global declaration of that
>   name. Consider what this would mean for operator functions! The
>   presence of *any* `operator+` function in the global scope would force
>   all friend `operator+` operators to appear in the global scope too!
>   The presence of a template in the global scope would have the same
>   effect.

For class types:

> ```
> namespace N {
>     class A { void f(); };
> }
>
> using namespace N;
>
> namespace M {
>     class B {
>         friend class A;  // Without this rule
>                          // makes N::A a friend
>         B();
>     };
>     class A { void f(); };
> }
>
> void N::A::f() { M::B  b; }  // A friend under current rules
>
> void M::A::f() { M::B  b; }  // A friend under proposed rules
> ```

Both examples are not as interesting under the current rules because names introduced via friend declarations are only found via ADL. It is possible this restriction is a historical artefact. **More "research" is required to follow the development of this restriction after the introduction of ADL.**

Comment: It's interesting because the example there does not yet require the additional declaration of `void f(int )`, so at that time `friend` was enough to declare it and make it visible already.